# Wrong NewItemPlaceholder Behavior

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some problems with `DataGrid`. When the `DataGrid` is set to `CanUserAddRows` a new black row is placed at the bottom of the `DataGrid` but these row have an unexpected behavior because if I just clik the new row and pass the focus to another cell the row is created even when it is empty. I would like to change the behavior by veryfing if the row is empty avoid the creation of new item but if in the event `RowEditEnding` I set `e.Cancel=true`, then the `NewItemPlaceHolder` desapears and I can not add any row since then. Any body has found the answer for these problem?

```
protected override void OnRowEditEnding(DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Row.Item as DataRowView).Row.ItemArray[0] == null || (e.Row.Item as DataRowView).Row.ItemArray[0].ToString() == String.Empty)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;

        IEditableCollectionView collection = Items as IEditableCollectionView;

        if (collection.IsAddingNew)
        {
            collection.CancelNew();
        }
    }            
    base.OnRowEditEnding(e);
}
```

Comment: I cancel the New because if I do not then an Exception of "DeferRefresh is not allowed for AddItem or NewItem transaction" is raised

Comment: I recommend using this solution! http://stackoverflow.com/a/42763784/973344

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found a way to do it by refreshing the CanUserAddRows property

```
bool canUserAddRows = Datagrid.CanUserAddRows;

                //Makes the refresh for CanUserAddRows because when cancel the new adding then collapse the NewPlaceHolder item
                Datagrid.CanUserAddRows = !canUserAddRows;
                Datagrid.CanUserAddRows = canUserAddRows;
```