# WPF Datagrid selected row from view to viewmodel and textblock

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a datagrid underneath there some textbox. I can't figure out how to transfer the datagrid selected row to the textblock and to viewmodel in MVVM.

```
<StackPanel>
            <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Height="300" Width="auto">
                <DataGrid x:Name="dtGrd" Width="800" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="Azure" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Cars, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Path=Id}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Brand" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Path=Brand}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Model" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Path=Model}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fuel" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Path=Fuel}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="MaxPassenger" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Path=MaxPassenger}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="NumberOfDoors" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Path=NumberOfDoors}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="AvailableType" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Path=AvailableType}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Path=Price}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid Margin="5" Height="150">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="225"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="225"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="225"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="225"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label Content="ID" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <!-- <TextBox x:Name="txtBxId" Padding="5" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=CurrentCar.Id, Mode=TwoWay}"/> -->
                <TextBox x:Name="txtBxId" Padding="5" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Id, ElementName=dtGrd, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <Label Content="Brand" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtBxBrand" Padding="5" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Brand, ElementName=dtGrd, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label Content="Model" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtBxModel" Padding="5" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Model, ElementName=dtGrd, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <Label Content="Fuel" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtBxFuel" Padding="5" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Fuel, ElementName=dtGrd, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label Content="MaxPassanger" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtBxMaxPassanger" Padding="5" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.MaxPassenger, ElementName=dtGrd, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <Label Content="NumberOfDoors" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtBxNumberOfDoors" Padding="5" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.NumberOfDoors, ElementName=dtGrd, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="3" Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label Content="AvailableType" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtBxAvailableType" Padding="5" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.AvailableType, ElementName=dtGrd, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <Label Content="Price" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtBxPrice" Padding="5" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Price, ElementName=dtGrd, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
```

I found that the SelectedItem binding will bind the selected row data to textboxes, but i can't transfer that to viewmodel.

I tried some random forum methods but none of them worked, the viewmodel didn't get any data from the view.

Answer (score 1):

You're close. I would bind the SelectedItem of the DataGrid to the ViewModel:

```
<DataGrid (...) SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCar, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" > (...)
```

That should be all you need, given that CanUsersAddRows stays false. Otherwise there is a slight issue as the user edits a new car.You then need to to add an converter to ignore the empty blank row eventuylly appearing at the end of the grid. You may find an Converter implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228629/bug-in-wpf-datagrid) or elsewhere.